# Posting images in chat using drag and drop

Tags: feature-request, chat, uploader

I think it will be a good idea if there is a drag and drop image posting in chat. User needs to follow many steps to upload an image using upload button.

Comment: This is a feature of [Porkchat](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/porkchat/genlcflidccakbiodbnmjnflfnbkmeip?hl=en-GB).

Comment: shouldn't they just bring over the imgur uploader from main into chat? /cc @ShadowWizard

Comment: @rene that would be one way to do that, yes. But for all we know, it might be very complicated hence maybe adding one feature at a time would be faster.